# When using the reinforcement learning model ddpg, the input data are sequence data

Tags: reinforcement-learning

When using the reinforcement learning model ddpg, the input data are sequence data, high-dimensional (21 dimensional) state and low dimensional (1-dimensional) action. Does this have any negative impact on the training of the model? How to solve it

Answer (score 0):

In general in any machine learning scenario, dimensionality per se is not a problem, it is mostly a matter of how much variability there is the input data. Of course, higher dimensional data can have much higher variability than lower dimensional one.

Even considering this, the problem can "easily" be solved by feeding more data to the ML algorithm and increasing the complexity that it is allowed to represent (i.e. more nodes and/or layers in a neural network).

In RL, this is even less of a problem because you don't really have a restriction on how much data you actually have. You can always run your agent some more on the environment to get more sample trajectories to train on. The only issue you might find here is that your computing time grows a lot (depending on how much more you need to train on the environment for this problem).